# How can I output results of tests ran with NUnit 3?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, nunit-3.0

Since yesterday I am trying to figure out how to create that XML report that NUnit3 can produce and I just can't find a single example with code.

What should I do in order to make NUnit 3 produce the results file or what and where should I be looking for?

Comment: How are you running your tests, via the NUnit Console runner? If so, it should write a TestResult.xml in the test directory. (Unless you are using a PCL framework build)

Comment: I am using the Visual Studio Test Explorer

Comment: This isn't currently possible with the VS adapter, but there's an open feature request: https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/215

If you use the NUnit Console, you should get the xml result file by default.

Comment: This would be easily done with the Resharper tool.

Answer (score 3):

This can definitely be done using `nunit3-console.exe` to run your project.

From a CMD/PowerShell console, call `\path\to\nunit3-console.exe \path\to\your.dll`. A `TestResult.xml` file is created in `\myProjectFolder\bin\Debug` by default. You can also add the `-out=` flag to additionally create a custom log.

For instance, `\path\to\nunit3-console.exe \path\to\your.dll -out=\path\to\whereever\testResultFileName.xml`. With a simple project, have a `[Test]` and a `Console.WriteLine()`. The testname and print statement will show up in your custom file.