# How to get nunit console 3 to output failed and ignored tests (only) to text files?

Tags: nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I understand that **nunit console 3** [can write to TestResult.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341184/how-to-output-results-of-tests-ran-with-nunit-3#comment73745716_43341184) after running the tests, where the `TestResult.xml` is located inside the directory specified by `--work` parameter.

But from what I can tell, `TestResult.xml` contains too many (irrelevant) details, that I don't need to fix my unit tests errors. All I need is just the failed or ignored test cases, just like what is displayed in command line prompt when I am running nunit console in it.

How to configure the parameters for nunit console 3 so that it only gives me failed or ignored test cases?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm a few months late *(unfortunately I came across this problem only now)*. But as far as I searched, the only possibility is to use XSL transformation. There are some applications that can convert the XML report file, but... I tested a few, but unfortunately the output was not that was I need.

Therefore I created a simple [NUnit3summary](https://github.com/JAD-SVK/NUnit3summary/releases) application that can transform the standard XML output file to text file. I was surprised that nobody until now made something like this *(or at least did not publish it)*. It were only two hours of work *(first working version)* and a few more to finish it to stare ready for publishing.

It is only a simple application that was aimed for my needs. You can  use filtration for now only with another application, e.g.:
`NUnit3summary.exe TestResult.xml | grep Failed >FailedTests.txt`

You can see a practical application [here](https://github.com/JAD-SVK/Gendarme/tree/FixUnitTests/UnitTests) *(this is also the project where the application was needed, because of too many errors in unit tests)*.